# Booting Fedora27.iso with grub2

Tags: fedora, grub2

I got a problem when I want to install Fedora 27 from iso file with grub2.

With several terrible hours searching the answer:

1. Format a USBFLashDrive into fat32.
2. Install grub2 to USBFlashDrive. In fedora/centos/redhat:

   ```
   #mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
   #mkdir /mnt/boot
   for efi#grub2-install --efi-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --removable /dev/sdX
   forbios#grub2-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdX
   ```
3. Write the boot entries in *grub.cfg*. 
   **So boring cause of many many be called correct**. After tried at least 20 times, got the solution here:

   ```
   menuentry 'Fedora-Workstation-netinst-x86_64-27-1.6' {
       set isofile='/boot/iso/Fedora-Workstation-netinst-x86_64-27-1.6.iso'
       loopback loop $isofile
       linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=Fedora-WS-dvd-x86_64-27 iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet
       initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
   }
   ```

[Reference](https://www.linuxsecrets.com/archlinux-wiki/wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive.html#Stock_installation_medium)

After got the correct reference, I was more confused thought problem was passed.
Can anyone point it out what part in iso file makes the boot entry in *grub.cfg* different? Specially what's the difference of **Stock installation medium** and **Workstation live medium** of Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Here is updated entry with boot option from "EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg" in iso. [use grub2-mkconfig to update grub.cfg with custom entry]

I put iso in root folder and here is what worked for me.

```
menuentry 'Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-27-1.6' {
    loopback loop (hd0,msdos1)/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-27-1.6.iso
    linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename="/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-27-1.6.iso" root=live:CDLABEL=Fedora-WS-Live-27-1-6 rd.live.image quiet
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initrd.img
}
```

Comment: does this work for fedora 30+?